# I can't access unc path from C#. Getting access is denied

Tags: c#, access-denied, unc

I'm using Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.5
I'm trying to access a file this way: \server\C$\temp\testFile.log from C# code running on another server.

My username is an admin on both servers. The code is running under that account. The temp folder has been set to full rights for (my user) and ASP.NET.

Why can't I access it?

I can't do a shared folder; against the rules. I am already running under full account; therefore, I don't need to do impersonation, right?

Comment: When you say you are using the 'admin' account on both machines, are you talking about local machine admin or domain/schema/etc admin?

Comment: Can you access the folder in Windows Explorer?

Comment: I want to also mention that I can access the path form a console application.

Comment: @Amy: yes I can access it on windows explorer... copy/paste.

Comment: @Dave: my user is an admin on the domain

Comment: Are you using two backslashes before the server name?  Your question shows only one.  And, of course, in C# you'd have to write that `string` as either `"\\\\server\\C$\\temp\\testFile.log"` or `@"\\server\C$\temp\testFile.log"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a web app? Are you sure the app is impersonating your account? Is anonymous access set to true in IIS?

Comment: You said: Are you sure the app is impersonating your account? Yes, I have tried impersonation, even though I didn't think I need it, based on this link: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306158#3. But when I saw your: "are you sure," it made me revisit and bumped on another link that gave me the correct impersonation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net (check Matt Johnson's answer). His solution worked like a charm!
So you kind of steered me the right direction. Thank you!
Note: the solution works even if IIS anonymous setting is set to false!

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could play some (if even very very minor) part in you getting the solution you needed. I only answered because those two things have come back to haunt me time and time again.

Answer (score 3):

Had this very same problem a while ago.

For your debug process to run with full Admin access, you'd have to open Visual Studio with full admin access.

In production, have your process "Run As Administrator".

If you do not do any of the above, you will have to implement impersonation.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known problem. Typical solutions use [WNetUseConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385482(v=vs.85).aspx).

See

1. [Accessing a Shared File (UNC) From a Remote, Non-Trusted Domain With Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659013/accessing-a-shared-file-unc-from-a-remote-non-trusted-domain-with-credentials)
2. [WNetUseConnection connects to remote server/UNC on same domain but not to a different/remote domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671961/wnetuseconnection-connects-to-remote-server-unc-on-same-domain-but-not-to-a-diff)

But my first guess would be to check [FileIOPermission](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.security.permissions.fileiopermission.aspx) as discussed in [Testing a UNC Path's “Accessability”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732347/testing-a-unc-paths-accessability)